# powershell dsc version 3.8.0.0 installation

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-5.0

I installed the new release of ps DSC 3.8.0.0 using:

```
Find-Module -Name xpsd* | Install-Module
```

I'm sure that as I'm writing this question, I had already restarted my PC at least once.
The problem is that the older version (3.7.0.0) DSC resource intellisense is what keeps appearing. Practically it's like the new module was never installed.

I attempted to delete the older dsc resources using:

```
Get-DSCResource | Where-Object{$_.Version -eq '3.7.0.0'} | Remove-Item
```

Which resulted in the modules not deleted but corrupted since they were listed as:

```
ImplementedAs   Name                      ModuleName                     Version    Properties                                        
-------------   ----                      ----------                     -------    ----------                                        
Binary          File                                                                {DestinationPath, Attributes, Checksum, Content...
```

Initially their `ImplementedAs` property had the value of `PowerShell`, which changed to `Binary` after the `Remove-Item` command. Also, their `ModuleName` and `Version` properties were populated correctly, before they became corrupted.

Using the `$env:PSModulePath`, I was able to locate the `3.7.0.0` folder and I deleted it.

Though the modules no longer show in the list retrieved by 'Get-DSCResource', I'm left with two problems:

1) How can I get DSC to use the new `3.8.0.0` resources, and its corresponding parameters?

Note: I tried `Find-Module -Name xpsd* | Install-Module -Force` which caused no improvement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently the [github documentation](https://github.com/PowerShell/xPSDesiredStateConfiguration) claim that there is a `Version` property in the `xPackage` resource is not accurate.

How do I know?

```
$res = Get-DSCResource xPackage
$res.Properties
```

The list of property items did NOT include a `Version` property. Thus, the DSC compiler was successfully using the newer version `3.8.0.0`, which to my surprise was followed by a newer release `3.9.0.0` within 3 weeks. The previous `3.7.0.0` release was published 13 months before the `3.8.0.0` release!!!

Comment: The properties returned are the writeable properties of the resource.  The `Version` property is a read property which is only returned by Get-DscConfiguration.  
Also, I don't see how this is related to the question.

Comment: @TravisPlunk Yes, my issue opened on the DSC github repo page was answered that the `Version` property is read only. They did give me a [detailed answer](https://github.com/PowerShell/xPSDesiredStateConfiguration/issues/103) that even thougth the version property appears as available in the `3.9.0.0`, it doesn't actually exist in the package resource!!! Which was the reason why I asked my question, at first.

Answer (score 2):

xPSDesiredStateConfiguration is the experimental module which we have made available in the gallery whereas PSDesiredStateConfiguration is what ships in box. In order to use resources from a module,  you need to import is using the Import-DscResource statement

```
Import-DscResource -ModuleName xPSDesiredStateConfiguration
```

Then you can use the resources as under:

```
xService MyService
{
}
```

Note that the resource names are different as well - with the ones in xPSDesiredStateConfiguration  having the "x" prefix in front of them

Comment: Okay, I included the `Import-DscResource` statement but the xPackage resource still doesn't include the `Version` property which is included in the documentation of `3.8.0.0`

Comment: What is the output of the following command 'Get-Module -List xPSDesiredStateConfiguration'

Comment: I apologize, the comment doesn't allow me to separate the lines. `Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`

      `ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands`                                                                   
      `---------- -------    ----                                ----------------`                                                                   
      `Script     3.8.0.0    xPSDesiredStateConfiguration        Publish-DSCModuleAndMof `